# Best way to write a generic method that checks whether a number is 0 in scala

Tags: scala

I know this is very trivial to do with a simple case check, but it seems it should be possible to write a method that does something like the following, that is generalizes to all numeric types:

```
  def checkNonZero(t: Long, field: String): List[String] = {
    if (t == 0) println("was zero") else println("wasn't zero")
  }
```

What's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This can be done with the `Number` type.

```
def checkNonZero(n: Number) = n != 0
```

Or you can use the `Numeric` typeclass.

```
def checkNonZero[T : Numeric](n: T) = { 
  val num = implicitly[Numeric[T]]
  !num.equiv(n, num.zero)
}
```

**EDIT**
Actually, you can just write it like this:

```
def checkNonZero[T : Numeric](n: T) = n != 0
```

Unless you define new custom instances of `Numeric` of course.

Answer (score 3):

An alternative way to Jasper-M's second solution goes as follows:

```
def isNotZero[A](n: A)(implicit num: Numeric[A]) = !num.equiv(n, num.zero)
```

This saves the line `val num = implicitly[Numeric[A]]`, while still allowing you to work with `num` if you so desire.

Despite this method actually taking 2 parameters, because the second one's implicit, you can use it like you would any other non-curried single-parameter method:

```
isNotZero(3) // true
isNotZero(0.1) // true
isNotZero(0) // false
isNotZero(0.0) // false
```